# Should i separate Pivot tables for each feature in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I'm building review product application where there are 3 database tables
- Review
- Categories
- Affiliates

At first i created a pivot table with 2 entries review_id & category_id & the sync was successfull. Later i added another column "affiliate_id" to the pivot table & the sync was successfull but with multiple entries. Let me explain

Here's my controller for review -

```
 $result->affiliates()->sync($aff_ids);
 $result->category()->sync($product);
```

The above code is creating sperate pivot entries -

Pivot Table -

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| review_Id | category_id | affiliate_Id |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|         1 | null        |   1          |
|         1 | 1           | null         |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Is the above pivot table correct or should i create seperate pivot tables for affiliates & categories ?

If the pivot table is not correct & if there is no need for seperate pivot tables then what i want to achieve is -

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| review_Id | category_id | affiliate_Id |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|         1 |           1 |            1 |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

The affiliate_id column can have have multiple entries so final result i want is -

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| review_Id | category_id | affiliate_Id |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|         1 |           1 |            1 |
|         1 |           1 |            2 |
|         1 |           1 |            3 |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: That looks like a ternary relationship. Laravel doesn't support those

Comment: so i should be creating sperate pivot table for affiliates ? containing review_id & affiliate_id ?

Comment: The question is: is the review directly related with the affiliate or does it also require the category in order for the relationship to make sense e.g. can you ever have the same review relating to multiple affiliates on the same category? If yes then you do have a genuine ternary relationship so you might need to keep this structure and work around laravel

Comment: Got your point, fixed it by creating pivot tables for affiliates too!

Answer (score 0):

use withPivot;

in Review Model class

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withPivot('affiliate_id');
}
```

Then

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
       $category_id_array[$category->id] = ['affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id];
}

//Insert into offence_photo table
$review->category()->sync($category_id_array, false);//dont delete old entries= false
```

Comment: I get your point but there is not point in using $categories since i'm retriving only one value - $request->get('category');